# Error in offline console game - Captain's Mode

Tags: technical-issues, dota-2

I used the following commands for starting a captain's mode game :

```
sv_lan 1
sv_cheats 1
dota_force_gamemode 2
map dota
```

I usually play all pick games with my friends, but in Captains mode, there are random bots popping up after the map loads.

Here is the console log : http://pastebin.com/EfDa4BKb

I want to get rid of the bots and want to play a Captains mode game with my friends. Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

Comment: isn't it possible to kick the bots after the game started? kickid <their ID here>

Comment: Nope. That just sets the bot state to disconnected. No one can replace that slot. I've tried that but good thinking :)

Comment: what about `dota_bot_disconnect_player ` ? you'll be able to control all bots yourself then.. so you could just let them sit back in base or something?

Comment: there is a [**discussion**](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=21042) about your problem at dev.dota2.com

Comment: You don't get it. I wanna play a game with my friends. Either way, the bots populate all the slots and my friends can't connect in because of this. I can control the bots but my friends cannot join in.

Comment: yea you're right i just missunderstood :D well i remember a nice guide for lan play i'll see if i can find it if it would help

Comment: already found it [**here on reddit**](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/2yf9q4/a_guide_on_how_to_lan_dota_2_with_steam_offline/) + explanation on how to play with/without bots.. hope that will help

Comment: I am fine with the lan commands, it's just the bots that is pissing me off :/

Comment: There is nothing more i can try so i'm out - sorry m8

Comment: I reproduce the exact same commands. It's probably just a bug. I will open an issue on dev.dota.com. Thanks mate :)

Comment: If the issue is accepted it would be great if you would answer your own question here with a short description and the link to the tracked issue

Comment: i think even the gameplay mode should be 4 for captain's mode.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible until you have 10 players. If you have 10 players, you can make a lobby and play, but internet is needed to make the lobby. Later, you can disconnect.

Comment: I am aware of this. But there are situations where we have limited access to the Internet. So yeah, I need a workaround.

Comment: Once you connect to land game you can disconnect your pc from Internet,,,, and play the game,,,, atleast for creating lobby you need

Answer (score -1):

Try
sv_lan1
sv_cheats 1
hostip (ip address of the server pc):27015
example--->hostip 192.168.43.19:27015
For the other pc's -->type connect 192.168.43.19:27015

dota_force_gamemode_2
map dota
then select dire or radiant.

Comment: Could you explain why this should fix the problem?